# How to change configuration of Facebook app with API graph?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

i need to change the configuration of an application with the API of facebook like the application domains, I have the *application id* and the *secret key* but I don't find how to make this request

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/application/#Updating

Comment: Ok, my bad,I wasnt using correctly the graph API, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The token generated automatically on the graph API doesn't work for get some data, I ahve to generate first the token with the correct call and assign this on request.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmgyT.png)